# How to recognize if given file or String is in Java Properties file format?

Tags: java, parsing, properties

How to recognize if given content (file, `String` or `InputStream`) is in **Java Properties** file format?

The content is stored in database and should be parsed into `Properties` **if** it is a properties file. However, with a simple test I've noticed, that `java.util.Properties` parsed without error an **xml** file `</log4j`). It could 'parse' also a normal text file.

So, if the `java.util.Properties` can parse practically everything what is text, how can I recognize if I have properties file or not? Need I check if this is in any other recognized format, can I use some heuristics or there is an existing library with such functionality?

Comment: this can be properties with any names that will be sent to another system. In other words, I can't expect any specific names or name convention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
private boolean isProperties(Scanner sc) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w.*[=:] *.+");
    int nProps = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
            if (!p.matcher(line).matches()) {
                sc.close();
                return false;
            }
            nProps++;
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    return nProps > 0;
}

public boolean isProperties(String s) {
    return isProperties(new Scanner(s));
}

public boolean isProperties(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return isProperties(new Scanner(f));
}

     ... more overloaded isProperties for different sources
```

This is just a prototype, regex may need improvement, see Properties.load API. I would ignore xml version, but if need be it's even simpler since there is DTD in API

Answer (score 2):

I would read the stream (file or string) e.g. into BufferedReader. Then, I would check for
properties on form of xml file:

Taken from javadoc:

```
The XML document must have the following DOCTYPE declaration:
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
```

So you can check for DOCTYPE (using reader and going through first lines or  - by parsing with xml parser, e.g. jdom). If DOCTYPE is there, use:

```
Properties.loadFromXML()
```

Otherwise you can look for line matching the pattern \s*\w+\s*=.*
so you will know that some assignment is made there, so it can be properties file, 
that you load with:

```
Properties.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the propertyNames() method to the resulting properties object and if you get back one or more names (you get back an Enumeration - use the hasMoreElements() method as your test) then you can assume it's a valid properties file.

Comment: The problem is that I get many names for something that isn't a properties file at all, for example it is the chapter from the book, and each first word from each line is the key, and the rest of the line is the value....

Comment: Then you're hosed.  An approach where you accept the properties in any format is not going to work.  This is more of an AI problem.

Comment: But having said that, this answers your specific question - How to tell if a file is in the Properties format.